# C typedef defined function

Tags: c

Within C how can I name a function? Just the name.

`typedef strlen StringLength` fails to compile with: `strlen does not name a type`.

Comment: try `#define StringLength strlen` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to "mock" a function - replacing the function call with another call - is to use `#define`. If you also don't want to worry about parameters, then simply do:

```
#define StringLength strlen
```

Function pointers might work too, but they may be restricted to a certain scope, and you must get the parameter and return types right. For `strlen` specifically, the correct type is (C11 7.24.6.3):

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

Thus a correctly defined function pointer should look like:

```
size_t (*const StringLength) (const char*) = strlen;
```

Where the `*const` makes the function pointer itself read-only, which is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

A function pointer is a solution

`static Integer(*StringLength)(const Byte*) = strlen;`

Comment: The text is wrong. It's not "static" which is working very well. `Integer(*StringLength)(const Byte*) = strlen;` would have worked the same. A function pointer works very well. Example [here](https://ideone.com/IHrdkp).

Comment: But the question should be: why abusing the language by aliasing function and type names this way?

Comment: Aliases to merge various functions into a non English project

Comment: If you are stuck with a bad code base written by someone in non-English, I can see how this would be useful. If you are however attempting to use this to translate standard function names into something else, that's simply madness and obfuscation. A person who can't read English simply can't work as a programmer - tough luck (I'm not native English either).

Comment: Unless of course the new function names make the project complete, as the project is written in another language, non English.!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility